# Create an object based on Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, typescript

```
let Array: any = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
```

How can I convert this array into an Object like below:

```
let Object: any = {
    time: {
        headerName: ""
    },
    monday: {
        headerName: "Monday"
    },
    tuesday: {
        headerName: "Tuesday"
    },
    wednesday: {
        headerName: "Wednesday"
    },
    thursday: {
        headerName: "Thursday"
    },
    friday: {
        headerName: "Friday"
    },
    saturday: {
        headerName: "Saturday"
    },
    sunday: {
        headerName: "Sunday"
    }
};
```

Any idea guys? Sorry am quiet new to JavaScript. How can I write a for loop so that i can achieve this result? Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yeah tried with looping through the Array. But I am stuck on the Object part

Comment: Was not sure how to continue. whether i declare the Object with my desired data Structure or not

Comment: Because as per the requirement, I have two keys. Day and the headername. How to create the frame or datastructure first guys?

Comment: Consider not naming your variables to `Array` and `Object`. You might have issues accessing globals with the same name in the scope of these variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply try this

```js
var any = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
var outputObj = { //create a new object with one default value
  time: {
    headerName: ""
  }
};
any.forEach(function(item) { //iterate the any array and then keep adding key and values to new Object
  outputObj[item] = {
    headerName: capitalizeFirstLetter(item)
  };
});

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

console.log( outputObj );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gurvinder. May I know whats the `any` array?

Comment: @blackdaemon it is the array having week days names as it is given in your question.

Comment: Oh you mean `Array`. can Thanks Gurvider

Comment: Let me try that method

Answer (score 5):

```js
var result = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"].reduce(function (acc, element) { 
     acc[element] = {};
     acc[element].headerName=element;
     return acc;
}, {time: ""});
console.log(result);
```

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example) to convert to object in JavaScript.

```
any.reduce(function (acc, element) { 
     acc[element] = {};
     acc[element].headerName=element;
     return acc;
}, {time: ""})
```

Comment: Please try running it before posting!

Comment: Much better now :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var any = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];

var res ={};
res['time'] ={headername:""};
any.map(function(a){
res[a] = {headername:a}

})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using For loop.
```

```js
function toObject(arr) {
  var rv = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i] !== undefined) rv[arr[i]] = {"headerName":arr[i]};
  console.log(rv);
}
toObject(["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]);
```